# Shopify Additional Scripts displaying on /orders/ path instead of just /checkouts/

Tags: ruby, shopify, tracking-pixel

I work with tracking pixels on a wide range of sites. We have an implementation that we've been using for Shopify that utilizes the "Additional Scripts" field in  Settings >> Checkouts to populate a tracking pixel to the checkouts "thank-you" page.

Currently we've been seeing some edge cases where the pixel set up like this seems to be displaying on other pages in the order tracking section of the site. Just wondering if anyone knows why this might be happening. Current theory is that one of the apps that all of these clients are using is causing the problem.

As an example, the standard pixel using this set up fires on

```
https://checkout.shopify.com/xxxxxxx/checkouts/yyyyyyyyyyyyy/thank_you
```

where xxxxxx and yyyyyy are the account and order numbers respectively. Currently we are seeing the pixel triggered from the same additional scripts firing on

```
https://checkout.shopify.com/xxxxxxxxx/orders/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Which obviously isn't stemming from the checkouts controller, which begs the question as to why a script defined in the settings for the checkout controller (which I believe edits the config file for the checkout directly) is ever changing this. When you visit the pages in the second format they contain order tracking status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a new URL format for the order status page. If the customer returns to the order status page (for example from an email that used the [`{{ order_status_url }}`](https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/notifications/email-variables#order-fulfillment) Liquid variable) then they'll see the `https://checkout.shopify.com/#{shop_id}/orders/#{order_token}` structure.

You can find out more from the announcement here: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/api-announcements/t/upcoming-changes-to-the-order-status-page-376181

Comment: Thank you sir. Just what I was looking for.